# Distinguishing between historical data of columns based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a dataset and it has the following information `[STUDENT_INFORMATION]`:

| STUDENT NAME | CLASS | DATE THEY TOOK THE CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sara | class 1 | 2/3/2018 |
| sara | class 2 | 3/3/2018 |
| Sara | class 3 | 6/3/2018 |
| max | class 1 | 1/4/2016 |
| max | class 2 | 1/4/2017 |
| max | class 3 | 1/4/2018 |
| ashley | class 2 | 9/4/2016 |
| ashley | class 3 | 10/8/2016 |
| ashley | class 2 | 9/4/2018 |
| ashley | class 3 | 10/8/2018 |

I want to get the information that displays students who took class 2 first and then class 3 right after taking class 2:

| STUDENT NAME | CLASS | DATE THEY TOOK THE CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sara | class 2 | 3/3/2018 |
| Sara | class 3 | 6/3/2018 |
| max | class 2 | 1/4/2017 |
| max | class 3 | 1/4/2018 |
| ashley | class 2 | 9/4/2018 |
| ashley | class 3 | 10/8/2018 |

So far I was thinking of the following, this would get the latest record by the name/class based on the timestamp, but I also want to get it so that we have class 2 right after class 3. is there a way to do that? Even if a student took the class twice ex (ashley)

```
SELECT   
    "STUDENT NAME",
    "CLASS",
    MAX("DATE THEY TOOK THE CLASS") 
FROM 
    STUDENT_INFORMATION
GROUP BY 
    "STUDENT NAME","CLASS"
```

Answer (score 0):

With lead() windows function, this can be achieved easily. The following query works in MySQL:

```
-- Prep data
create table student_infomation (
    student     varchar(20),
    class       varchar(20),
    class_date  date);
    
insert into student_infomation 
values
('sara'  , 'class 1', '2018-02-03'),
('sara'  , 'class 2', '2018-03-03'),
('sara'  , 'class 3', '2018-06-03'),
('max'   , 'class 1', '2016-01-04'),
('max'   , 'class 2', '2017-01-04'),
('max'   , 'class 3', '2018-01-04'),
('ashley', 'class 2', '2016-09-04'),
('ashley', 'class 3', '2016-10-08'),
('ashley', 'class 2', '2018-09-04'),
('ashley', 'class 3', '2018-10-08');


-- SQL query
with cte as (
select student,
       class,
       class_date,
       lead(class, 1)      over (partition by student order by class_date) as next_class,
       lead(class_date, 1) over (partition by student order by class_date) as next_class_date
  from student_infomation)
select *
  from cte
 where class      = 'class 2'
   and next_class = 'class 3';
```

Result:

```
student|class  |class_date|next_class|next_class_date|
-------+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
ashley |class 2|2016-09-04|class 3   |     2016-10-08|
ashley |class 2|2018-09-04|class 3   |     2018-10-08|
max    |class 2|2017-01-04|class 3   |     2018-01-04|
sara   |class 2|2018-03-03|class 3   |     2018-06-03|
```